# save arrayList<Class> as a string inside Room

Tags: java, arraylist, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using Room library from jetpack and i want to save my arrayList inside Room database.

I am using typeConverter to convert arrayList into String, but still getting error.

```
Error Message : Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

this is my typeConverter.

```
public class TypeConverterUtils {
    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArray(ArrayList<CropData> arrayList) {
        return GsonUtils.toGson(arrayList);
    }
}
```

this is my Database class.

```
@TypeConverters({TypeConverterUtils.class})
public abstract class CheruvuDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Cheruvu.db";

    public abstract OtpDAO otpDAO();

    public abstract FarmerInfoDAO farmerInfoDAO();

    // For Singleton instantiation
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static volatile CheruvuDatabase sInstance;

    public static CheruvuDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (sInstance == null) {
                    context.getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(CheruvuDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);
                    sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), CheruvuDatabase.class, CheruvuDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

I want to store this ArrayList.

private ArrayList cropData = new ArrayList<>();

this is my CropData class.

```
public class CropData {

    private String cropName;
    private Crop crop;
    private Float cropAcres;
    private Float cropYield;
    private Float cropPrice;

    public String getCropName() {
        return cropName;
    }

    public void setCropName(String cropName) {
        this.cropName = cropName;
    }

    public Crop getCrop() {
        return crop;
    }

    public void setCrop(Crop crop) {
        this.crop = crop;
    }

    public Float getCropAcres() {
        return cropAcres;
    }

    public void setCropAcres(Float cropAcres) {
        this.cropAcres = cropAcres;
    }

    public Float getCropYield() {
        return cropYield;
    }

    public void setCropYield(Float cropYield) {
        this.cropYield = cropYield;
    }

    public Float getCropPrice() {
        return cropPrice;
    }

    public void setCropPrice(Float cropPrice) {
        this.cropPrice = cropPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are getting an error you should include the error message in your question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added @Embedded on the ArrayList variable? because you will be needed to Embed the Class, that you want to convert.

for example,

```
ArrayList<CropData> cropData;
```

and CropData.class is different. so just add

```
@Embedded 
ArrayList<CropData> cropData;
```

and your problem will be solved.